# 'android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource' happened in release apk

Tags: android

I recently run into this issue. It tells me that can't find this string resource.

[image: Resources$NotFoundException]

But it's weird.  I've already define this string in xml, and there was nothing wrong when debugging. 
[image]

[image]

It is only happened in the release apk, and when I clear the whole project and rebuild a new apk without any change in code or resource, everything works just fine.

I wonder how to avoid crash like this. Thanks.

Comment: Check if your gradle file has proguard, or other optimization/compression enabled. Sometimes these remove things you actually want.

Comment: Use resources for getting the string. It can be helpful. Like String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.mystring);

Comment: Try this way`textView.setText(getString(R.string.your_String)`

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Either use 'getResource().getString()' or use 'setText(string id)’ are both ok  now. I guess somethings went wrong in caches or proguard, because it work well after clean project.